# Simple speedometer animation in SVG and CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg

So I'm trying to make a CSS3 animation with an SVG icon, wherein the needle rotates across the speedo, while maintaining a fixed point at the center.

In this case, I'm attempting to do the animation from right to left (as if the speedometer were going to zero), but can't seem to do it right. I've come close with the following:

```
<g>
    <path fill="#C6A3A3" id="arrow" d="M26.323,23.042c-0.256,0-0.513-0.098-0.707-0.293c-0.392-0.391-0.392-1.023,0-1.414l9.899-9.899
    c0.391-0.391,1.022-0.391,1.414,0c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414l-9.899,9.899C26.834,22.944,26.578,23.042,26.323,23.042z"/>
</g>
```

(there is more to the SVG but this is the relevant piece)

And the SCSS file:

```
@keyframes speedo {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-120deg);
  }
}

#arrow {
  fill: rgb(66, 169, 97);
  animation: speedo 2s ease infinite;
  transform-origin: 30px 20px 10px;
}
```

From that, I only get this: 
[image]

It rotates around its own center, rather than the centre of the speedo itself. I've seen people place transforms around the `<g>` element, but I'm not sure how to apply them. Also, `transform-origin: bottom left` doesn't help. I'm still trying to get to grips with CSS transforms/animations, especially as they relate to SVGs, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
transform-origin:center bottom;
```

will work if the needle image was straight to begin with. It looks like the problem is that the needle image is angled. Let CSS create the angles.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `transform-origin` it let's you choose where there animations anchor point is, try this:

`transform-origin:center bottom;`

Mare can be found here: [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Comment: That answer gives the following animation, which is incorrect: http://i.imgur.com/vl6iRIu.gif